# Simplify and Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Am I missing something here? Thanks for any help! SN

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This could be a bug. For now, you can use `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify`

```
f = -z*Sqrt[-((-1 + z)*z)]
g = Sqrt[-((-1 + z)*z^3)]
Simplify[f + g, Assumptions -> 0 <= z <= 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullSimplify[f + g, Assumptions -> 0 <= z <= 1]

  (* 0 *)
```

And please post plain text code next time. Hard to copy all this from an image and could make mistake.

Comment: It seems that the bug might be linked to `Simplify[f + g, Assumptions -> 0 <= z]` not calling `Log` internally contrarily to the other cases. My claim is based on `DeleteDuplicates@
 Cases[Trace[Simplify[f + g, Assumptions -> 0 <= z], TraceInternal -> True], _Log, All]` and comparing with `FullSimplify` and including `0 <= z<= 1` with `Simplify`